# Bottom Sheet and ListView

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

When I scroll down in the ListView, BottomSheep starts to close. Is there any way to do this so that the interaction of closure happens only when you touch the Bottom Sheet Peek (with an example). Also, an example is interested in where Bottom Sheet is blocked by touching a finger, that is, opening and closing is done by code.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because nested scroll events are being passed up to the bottom sheet. What you need to do is disable this behaviour by setting `isNestedScrollingEnabled` to false (Kotlin) or `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` (Java).

This has to be set in a direct child of the Bottom Sheet but this child needs to support nested scrolling. So, wrap the `ListView` inside a `NestedScrollView`, `SwipeRefreshLayout` or anything that supports nested scrolling and disable nested scrolling as below

```
swipeRefreshLayout?.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
```

or in java

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: But i replace false on true, and this helped me.